# Trying to calculate a value for each text file in a directory but it only gives me the result of one

Tags: python

I have a file with 4000 genes, and my goal is to calculate the % of GC content every 3 bases. So far, I have managed to import each file and calculate the total base number for each, but for some reason, it only gives me one % value at the end. I have two proposed methods for calculating the number of Gs and Cs, but have only tried running the first one

I'm new to this so any explanation would be great

```
#final code
#imports all extracted gene txt files from the directory
import os
import io
import glob

work_dir = "folder/"
for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(work_dir, "*.txt")):
    with io.open(path, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as dir:
        genome = dir.read()

#calculates the GC3 content of each txt file
    total_base = len(genome)
    print("Total no of bases:" + str(total_base))

c_count = 0
g_count = 0
for i in range(0, len(genome), 3):
   if genome[i] == "g":
       #dont need another variable here
       g_count += 1
   if genome[i] == "c":
       c_count += 1

#OR another method is:
g = genome[::3].count('g')
c = genome[::3].count('c')
print("Number of G bases:"+str(g))
print("Number of C bases:"+str(c))

#calculates final GC3 content in %
GC3 = ((g+c)/total_base) * 100
print("GC3 content in % :" + str(GC3))
```

Comment: You are opening each file but you aren't doing the calculation for each file. That's because the code for the calculation is outside the loop and won't be executed until the loop is finished when the data im genome will be from the last file. Do you want to do the calculation, and store it, for each file or should the result be an aggregation of the calculation for all the files?

Comment: @norie Thanks for your help! i've got it working now :)